# Calling a perl script as a shell command

Tags: perl, shell, exec

I want to call my perl script as a command from command line.
Example lets say I have a perl file like following

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
@args =("mvn","package");
    system(@args) == 0
    or die "system @args failed"
```

I right not call this using package.pl

I tried doing the following

```
#!/bin/sh
  eval 'exec /bin/perl –x -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0; 
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
@args =("mvn","package");
    system(@args) == 0
    or die "system @args failed"
```

and then name the file 'package' .Do chmod on package

When I try to run package, then I get the error 
"Can't open perl script []x:No such file or directory

Can someone please point me out , as to how to do this properly??

Thanks

Neeraj

Comment: You need to be using double quotes in your eval, not single quotes.

Comment: Your perl file doesn't need to end in `.pl`: Perl doesn't care.  Just use `#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w` at the top of a file called `package`.  File name suffixes are really just a Dos/Windows thing

Comment: Still seems to throw the same error.

Comment: Where really is your perl executable? /bin/perl or /usr/local/bin/perl?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, Single quotes are fine if `/bin/sh` is really `sh` or compatible with `sh` (like `bash`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the name you want to use and make it executable:

```
cp package.pl package
chmod +x package
```

Run it:

```
package
```

or:

```
./package
```

Comment: or *alias* it, if you're on *NIX.

Answer (score 2):

Changed single quotes to double quotes and escaped inner double quotes. Also, there seems to be some problem with paths. Try calling your script with absolute path. I tried adding "./" and it worked:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "This is shell"

eval "exec /usr/bin/perl -x -S ./$0 ${1+\"$@\"}"
   if 0;

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "This is Perl\n";
```